# Prefill Html Editor Asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I want to fill with a value of the `@Html.Editor` when the page is loaded. Here is my failed attempt :

```
 @Html.EditorFor(m => m, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
```

At the top of the Razor page , I have this :

```
@model string
```

And this is my controller :

```
public ActionResult YeniBelge(string KimlikNo)
{
    return View((object)KimlikNo);
}
```

It says value can't be null.

How can I make this correct? Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Html.Editor not rendering the value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4809275/html-editor-not-rendering-the-value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you are trying to assign a string that could be null to your model, which can never be null. Create a ViewModel class and use it instead:

```
public class MyViewModel {
    public string TCKimlikNo { get; set; }
}

public ActionResult YeniBelge(string KimlikNo)
{
    return View(new MyViewModel { KimlikNo = KimlikNo ?? "My Default Value" });
}
```

And then in your view:

```
@model MyViewModel

@Html.EditorFor(m => m.TCKimlikNo, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control"  } })
```

Comment: While debugging, I can see the value in `YeniBelge` controller, so the value is not null. But it still gives that error. Anyway I'm going to try your suggestion. Thanks.

Comment: If you have an exception you should have added (message and stacktrace) to the question. Otherwise is not possible to understand what is causing it.

Comment: It gives the "Value can't be null exception" in the `EditorFor` line.

Comment: I think @FedericoDipuma has hit the nail on the head, but within the view you are not getting the model. I have tried to show an example below. But Fedrico is the first to answer this.

Answer (score 1):

Fill your model with data in controller, then use

```
@Html.EditorFor(m=>m);
```

Answer (score 1):

Like @vortex pointed out you need to use the EditorFor template.

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.TCKimlikNo, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control"  } })
```

If you have your model loaded at the top of the page this will fill in the form with the current value of the model field.

Answer (score 1):

In your controller change to the following.

```
  public class KimlikNoViewmodel
    {
        public string KimlikNo { get; set; }
    }

    public ActionResult YeniBelge (string KimlikNo)
    {
        KimlikNoViewmodel viewModel = new KimlikNoViewmodel();
        viewModel.KimlikNo = KimlikNo;

        return View(viewModel);
    }
```

in your view I suspect that you are not finding the model. You need to include your project name when calling the Model.

```
@model YourProjectName.Controllers.KimlikNoViewmodel
```

I would suggest actually saving the View model we created within the Models folder under a View models file and then you would call the following instead.

```
@model YourProjectName.Models.KimlikNoViewmodel
```