# How to pass a string from Controller to View in ASP.NET MVC5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have this controller :

```
public ActionResult MyController(string myString)
{
    return View((object)myString);
}
```

I'm trying to pass the string to view like this :

```
@model string
@Html.EditorFor(m => m)
```

I get value can't be null error. How can I fix this? Thanks.

Comment: Refer [this question/answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43309582/prefill-html-editor-asp-net-mvc) for how to handle this.

Answer (score 7):

First of all, I would recommend to change your Action method name. Why you name it like MyController. It should be a meaningful method name.

Then come to your issue. If your view is only for display purpose, not for form post, then you can bind your string in a `viewbag` and render in your view.

For example, in your action method,

```
ViewBag.MyString = myString;
```

And in your view,

```
<p>@ViewBag.MyString</p>
```

But if you want to edit your string in view and after click a submit button, it should post the value to server, then create a `view model`, for example,

```
public class MyStringModel
{
  public string MyString { get; set; }
}
```

In your action method,

```
public ActionResult MyController(string myString)
{
  MyStringModel = new MyStringModel();
  MyStringModel.MyString = myString;
  return View(MyStringModel)
}
```

Then in your view,

```
@model MyStringModel
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.MyString)
```

See, you need to add `@HTML.BeginForm` and a `submit button` in your view to `post back` your string data.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

Also you can pass information to your view with the ViewBag, ViewData, TempData all with different information lifecyle.

Check this:

http://royalarun.blogspot.com.ar/2013/08/viewbag-viewdata-tempdata-and-view.html

With your example the model is associated with a dictionary so you can not use directly the property like this.

For your example and just pass only a string from the controller you can do any like  this:

```
public ActionResult MyController(string myString)
{
    return View(model:myString);  
}
```

and in the .cshtml (if you use c#)

```
@model string
@{
    var text = Model;
}
@Html.EditorFor(m => text);
```

**But I think is a better solution pass a viewMoedel with a string property like the @Stephen Muecke response**  [Prefill Html Editor Asp.net MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43309582/prefill-html-editor-asp-net-mvc)

Comment: Wrong - it does need to be cast to `object` (other wise if would call the overload where the parameter is the view name)

Comment: Yes you are right, but in the example I use model param declaration, look again :) @ Stephen Muecke

Comment: That's fine, but your first statement is wrong and misleading (OP's usage was fine)!

Comment: Maybe I can change to it's not really necesary but it's fine to OP ? :)

Comment: The issue is with the `HtmlHelper` method and the solution is to use a view model as per the link in my comment to the question :)

Comment: Yes sure ! I think it's better that just pass the string, "you can create an object with a string property"  :) THKS so.. you are right.

Comment: That `View(model:myString)` really helped me out.  I was trying to following MS docs (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/partial?view=aspnetcore-5.0) to create a simple `PartialView` example but I was getting a really strange error where my View was not found even though the Action (GetBook) & the Views directory \Download really existed the dotnet core MVC app gave this crazy error -- I was attempting to pass just the string into the View(). It was using the string to the View as the view filename. Very odd, but that got me past it. thanks
Where did you find that syntax?

Comment: Ok, I got it: model: is named argument on View() constructor -- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controller.view?view=aspnetcore-5.0#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_Controller_View  Thanks